# F.lux don't work on dual monitors (laptop + external)?

Tags: 14.04, multiple-monitors

First things first, this question is already [asked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/217275/can-f-lux-work-with-dual-screen-laptop-external-setup), but is 2 years old and without an answer. Now my problem...

I have one monitor with another from my laptop. That's my workspace. But when I install f.lux the app only worked on the laptop's monitor and not on the external. Why? I tried Redshift but I can't lower down the redness on the screens and unfortunately, it works on dual monitors.

So can someone share some workaround?

Thank you.

p.s. I have Ubuntu 14.04 32bit

Comment: I can recommend [Redshift](//apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/redshift/) as an alternative. It's (mostly) functionally equivalent to f.lux, but FOSS and much better integrated with Linux in general and Ubuntu in particular. I never had issues with it my dual-monitor Xinerama setup. It also lets you configure pretty much any colour temperature you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to install the package via apt-get and then manually download a modified version of the daemon file "xflux" (this is not the GUI) for your 32bit-System from https://justgetflux.com/linux.html under "xflux daemon (command line, but for X-Windows)".

I shut down the GUI before I did this and when starting it again, it worked.

I found this solution here: https://github.com/Kilian/f.lux-indicator-applet/issues/16

Comment: Works well, thanks. Just don't understand why it's not accepted as solution.

Comment: xflux works flawlessly

Answer (score 0):

Just installed fluxgui from https://launchpad.net/~nathan-renniewaldock/+archive/ubuntu/flux and it seems to work fine with my 3 screens xrandr config.